# actual data encryption key is used to encrypt PV in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pvc, google-cloud-kms

In GKE cluster, I get to encrypt a dynamically provisioned PV using customer supplied key (using Cloud KMS).
I specify KMS resource name in storage class, and create PVC out of this.

It is unclear to me, which key is used to encrypt data in PV.
Is it directly using the key that I specify in storage class, or *another* data encryption key (which in turn is encrypted using specified key in KMS - aka envelope encryption)?

Answer (score -1):

By default, Google Cloud encrypts [customer content at rest](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption/default-encryption), and GKE manages encryption for you without any action on your part.

If you want to control and manage encryption key rotation yourself, you can use [CMEK](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/using-cmek). **These keys encrypt the data encryption keys that encrypt your data**. For more information, see [Key management](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption/default-encryption#key_management). You can also encrypt secrets in your cluster using keys that you manage. For details, see [Application-layer secrets encryption](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/encrypting-secrets).

For more details,refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/exploring-container-security-use-your-own-keys-to-protect-your-data-on-gke).

Comment: Doesn’t help. Plus, question is GKE centric, so is cloud storage even relevant? In GKE, one would work with PV (CSI driver based)

Comment: @C. Derx. Thank You for the inputs. I have now updated my answer with the findings on How encryption keys are used in GKE.

Comment: I've relooked at the links, and nowhere I see where it clearly states that specified KMS key is used to encrypt the data encryption keys that encrypt PV data.  It's clear what envelop encryption does, it's unclear if that is what is happening during PV encryption case in GKE (not a Cloud storage used in VM). Application layer encryption in GKE is different to PV encryption - that is not the focus here.

Comment: The Encryption and Decryption of disk content is not done by GKE, nor encryption keys 
 are stored in K8s or etcd. Instead the encryption, decryption, and key management are features of GCP Persistent Disk.